# How to migrate umbraco blog to wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, migration, content-management-system, umbraco

My client wants to move blog posts from Umbraco (.NET CMS) to a WordPress blog.
They have just provided the URL for Umbraco.

How do I move the content of this blog from Umbraco to WordPress?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to export the posts from Umbraco in xml/json format and then import this into your wordpress site.

I would suggest you either check if there's already RSS features in your blog that would allow you to read all the posts as XML - if that is not the case, it should be fairly easy to create a new template in Umbraco, simply looping through all descendant nodes in the blog, showing the content of each blog post as XML data instead of rendering HTML for the browser.

Then you would need to import this in Wordpress somehow. The Wordpress part I'm not that familiar with but there's most likely some plugin that can do this for you.

I don't know of any packages/plugins that can help you do exports (only imports) from umbraco since the exports are usually easier to do manually so the format is what you expect.

Comment: ok. 
I will try to export the post from Umbraco using the Template method as per your guidance.Thanks.

Comment: No problem - if you get stuck, try searching for how people create sitemaps in Umbraco. I guess a sitemap template could be modified to do what you want to do and it has the logic for looping through content in the site.

Comment: Surely will check it. Thanks you so much. @claus :)